# AngularJS Is it possible to listen to $destroy in another controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-events

In my application, When a controller is being destroyed, is it possible to the $destroy event it emits in another controller?

Comment: can you not use any other custom event name other than `$destroy`? you are not wanting to listen to controller being destroyed anyway..

Comment: If it's not being destroyed I assume the $destroy event won't go off either... Soo.. No.

Comment: When a controller and it's scope is being destroyed it fires the $destroy event. What I was wondering is if I can listen to this $destroy event in another controller, that's all.

Comment: Just so I don't have to broadcast/emit an event manually in each controller. Just for efficiency.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It looks like XY problem.

Comment: The reason shouldn't be relevant, I was simply asking if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a factory/service to register callback that would be called on controller destruction

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, notifyService) {
  $scope.logs = []
  notifyService.callback = function(){
    $scope.logs.push('controller destroyed on: ' + new Date().toString())
  }
});

app.controller('directiveController', function($scope, notifyService){
  $scope.$on('$destroy', notifyService.callback)
})

app.service('notifyService', function(){
  this.callback = angular.noop
})

app.directive('toggleDirective', function(){
  return {
    template: "<div>I'm directive with controller that will be destroyed</div>",
    controller: 'directiveController'
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJ2sbJSOyYZyQxAWzOxS?p=preview